# Does anybody can help me figure out how to display.... in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Does anybody can help me figure out how to display this cells right here.

[image: Image 1]

To right here. Using the specific name displayed on image 1. Like i want to filter them.

[image: Image 2]

I tried using

```
=VLOOKUP("John Alexis Ramos",ARRAYFORMULA({$B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7}),2, 0)
```

But it only shows this

[image: Image 3]

Comment: Pls, share a spreadsheet instead of images.

Comment: If you want to get more than only one information, use query instead of vlookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=FILTER({$A2:$A7,$C2:$D7},$B2:$B7=I25)
```